# How to convert a Base64 String to a byte array in java (signed char)?

Tags: java, base64, byte

I need to convert a Base64 String (UTF-8) to an array of bytes in java. The logic I've used was not able to accomplish that properly. I guess this code does not take into consideration the indication for signed or unsigned char. I runs with no erros, but the results are not the expected ones. How Can I get the byte array considering possible negative values?

```
        Base64 decoder = new Base64();
        byte[] decodedBytes = (byte[]) decoder.decode(getInfo().getBytes());

        for (int i = 0; i < decodedBytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(decodedBytes[i]);
        }
```

```
private static String getInfo() {
        return "+//q/93/4v/0//7/AAD0/+f/6v/7/wIA9P/g/9v/7P/x//H/5//b/+D/9v/+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";
    }
```

I say the results are not the expected because I have to make a graphic with the array values and compare it to another existing one and currently the drawings are different.

Updating... What if I wanted to get 16 bits at a time instead of only 8?

Comment: This code doesn't have any problems relating to signed vs. unsigned.  (Except the `System.out.println`.)

Comment: What's wrong with System.out.println?

Comment: Most things don't actually care about the signedness or unsignedness of bytes, and process them correctly no matter what.  System.out.println is going to treat them as signed.

Comment: *"but the results are not the expected ones"* What did you expect? What did you actually get?

Comment: *"code does not take into consideration the indication for signed or unsigned char"* Base-64 doesn't have anything to do with signed or unsigned *char*. Base-64 is about encoding *bytes* in ASCII-only characters.